# Angular: Passing data or events from child to parent with router-outlet

Tags: angular

I have parent AppComponent with routes login, home etc. When user logs in with creds, I'm saving the user creds in Sessionstorage. When the login is successful I want to display some part of the data in header of AppComponent.html, so I have to getItems from seesionstorage. How do I trigger the event to notify AppComponent from LoginComponent? I'm using router-outlet so I cannot use EventEmitter. I can use BehaviourSubject but there is no valid method in AppComponent to call.
Please suggest.

Comment: Do you just want to check in Appcomponent if some action is perfomed in Login component ? You can use a communication service to emit your changes to other component

Comment: @warrior I want AppComponent to fetch data from sessionstorage when the login in LoginComponent is successful

Comment: You can do this by event emitters

Comment: Yes after login you can emit changes to appComponent from logincomponent and in your appcomponent you can fetch data from storage

Comment: @warrior How can I emit the event since it is router-outlet? There is no login selector or template directly injected in AppComponent

Comment: There is no need to use selector or template ... you can use a communication-service for this

Comment: @warrior How do I pass the event?? In template we can write like (someEvent) = parentMethod($event). How to achieve this at component level?

Comment: I have posted an answer please check

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use communication service for this:

CommunicationService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class CommunicationService {
    constructor() { }

    private emitChangeSource = new Subject<any>();

    changeEmitted$ = this.emitChangeSource.asObservable();

    emitChange() {
        this.emitChangeSource.next();
    }
}
```

login.ts:

```
constructor(
    private communicationService: CommunicationService
    ) {
   }

   login(){
    this.communicationService.emitChange()
   }
```

AppComponent.ts:

```
constructor(
    private communicationService: CommunicationService,
    ) { 
    communicationService.changeEmitted$.subscribe(data => {
      // here fetch data from the session storage 
    })
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please explain your solution @Aakriti.G

Comment: this is what i was looking for thank you  @Aakriti.G

Answer (score 1):

am just expanding 'Hrishikesh Kale' answer a bit, from your view, you are storing user credentials in localstorage.

just get that stored data in service

```
credentials(){
    const usercredential = localStorage.getItem('usercredential')
    if(usercredential === "undefined"){
      return false
    }
    else {
      return true
    }
  }
```

and in your html

```
<a *ngIf="service.loggedIn() && service.credentials()">Admin</a>
```

Comment: you can modify logic as you want return true | false