# Passing data between components using EventEmitter when Routing is used

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

The question is if it is possible and how to pass data between components using EventEmitter (@Output, @Input) when Routing is used to navigate from parent component to children.

For example, if I don't use Routing like below, this is completely feasible.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>RSVP</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <app-events (eventClicked)="childEventClicked($event)"></app-events>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <app-event-details [event]="clickedEvent"></app-event-details>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, in case I need to navigate to AppEventsComponent (app-events) or to AppEventDetailsComponent (app-event-details) using Routing navigation how is this possible?

Comment: I believe you'd have to use a service

Comment: No. In this case, you would pass the ID of the clicked event in the details URL, and the details component would get the details from the server, using the ID in the URL (obtained from ActivatedRoute).

Comment: you could use a resolver

Answer (score 0):

you can use local storage to pass data from one component to another like
set localstorage

> localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

and you can recieve that value in other component using

> localStorage.getItem("lastname");

and other way you can pass value in router params and then call api to get same data

Answer (score 0):

I think I am asking the same with this [Angular: Passing data or events from child to parent with router-outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901589/angular-passing-data-or-events-from-child-to-parent-with-router-outlet)
So, what is more convenient for me is to use a service.